# How to write a REST Get-Request in C#?

Tags: c#, api, rest, curl, get

I am new to C# and still try to get familiar with its environment.

I'd like to make a REST-Request in Get-Mode. The guys who gave me the API-Access provided me with following information:

```
HTTP Methods: GET
Authentication: None
Formats: xml
Parameters: format, apikey [GET], lang [GET], q [GET]
CURL Example: curl --get --data lang="de" --data q="query" --data apikey="QWERTY123456" http://jokr.info/api/v8/search/item.xml
```

And I don't know how to put this in C#.
I tried to use **WebClient** but I do not know how to put my request with the parameters in action.

Comment: Can you show your WebClient method so we can see what's wrong with it ?

Comment: use google to find a REST library. on wikipedia there is a thesis linked about REST that is helpful to read.

Answer (score 4):

There is a popular library [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

Here is an exemple :

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
var request = new RestRequest("api");
request.AddParameter("foo", "bar");

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    // do something with the response
});
```

Which translates to http://example.com/api?foo=bar

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string URI = "http://jokr.info/api/v8/search/item.xml"; 
string myParameters = "myparam1=value1 & myparam2=value";

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = webClient.UploadString(URI, myParameters);  
}
```